# How to gently ask PostgreSQL to add PostGIS extension

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I have recently installed PostGIS for the first time. 
I'm trying to use psycopg2 to create some polygon features.

This runs:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test_insert_shape (uuid varchar PRIMARY KEY, wkt polygon);')
```

Then this runs:

```
cur.execute('CREATE INDEX test_insert_shape_polygon_idx ON test_insert_shape USING GIST (wkt);')
```

Then this fails:
wkt comes from shapely and should not be the problem
Doesn't matter if I use different names for wkt, the error is the same
while using wkt geometry (Polygon) makes a new error Missing datattype geometry

```
cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO test_insert_shape (uuid, wkt) VALUES (\'iaufiubasdfasdfgsd\', ST_GeomFromText( \'POLYGON ((689370 7724110, 689370 7724130, 689350 7724130, 689330 7724130, 689330 7724170, 689350 7724170, 689350 7724230, 689370 7724230, 689370 7724210, 689410 7724210, 689430 7724210, 689430 7724130, 689410 7724130, 689410 7724110, 689370 7724110))\', 25833);')
```

Error:

LINE 1: SELECT ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON ((
               ^
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. (ST_GeomFromText)

Then I try to enable postgis extension:

```
try:
    cur.execute('CREATE EXTENSION postgis;')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I get ProgrammingError: extension "postgis" already exists

I try to see what functions is available in the pgadmin under databasename.Schemas.public.Functions

I see none..

How can I enable this function?

Or is there a better way to insert polygon geometry?

For those used to FME. I actually get an error there to:
ERROR |Error executing SQL command ('select version(), postgis_version()'): 'ERROR:  function postgis_version() does not exist
LINE 1: select version(), postgis_version()

versions: 
POSTGIS: 2.5 r15475 http://postgis.net/source
CGAL VERSION: 4.11 http://www.cgal.org
Boost VERSION: 1.59.0 http://www.boost.org
GMP VERSION: 5.1.2 https://gmplib.org
MPFR VERSION: 3.1.2 http://www.mpfr.org
PROTOBUF VERSION: 3.2.0 https://github.com/google/protobuf
PROTOBUF-C VERSION: 1.2.1 https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c
GEOS VERSION: 3.7.1 http://trac.osgeo.org/geos
GDAL VERSION: 2.2.4 trac.osgeo.org/gdal
PROJ VERSION: 4.9.3 trac.osgeo.org/proj
CGAL VERSION: 4.11 cgal.org
BOOST VERSION: 1.59.0 boost.org
SFCGAL VERSION: 1.3.2 github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL

Comment: Your title and body ask different questions. What you're really asking is "What is the correct format of WKT to represent polygons?" The answer is to not put parens around vertices.

Comment: The format of wkt seen here is just my fast typing off it. I use shapely to get the correct wkt.

Comment: You have created your table to have a column "wkt" of type "polygon" which is a native PostgreSQL type https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/datatype-geometric.html. What you want is to have a column that is of the Postgis type "geometry".

Comment: Thanks for the information. But it still complains about the missing function.

Comment: I do ask that question, because I believe it has something to do with the postgis extension not beeing activated or something.

Comment: Please add the complete WKT of your polygon so it can be checked. And edit your question to show how your create table looks now. Your error is probably here `)))'` because you are closing the WKT too early.

Comment: POLYGON ((689370 7724110, 689370 7724130, 689350 7724130, 689330 7724130, 689330 7724170, 689350 7724170, 689350 7724230, 689370 7724230, 689370 7724210, 689410 7724210, 689430 7724210, 689430 7724130, 689410 7724130, 689410 7724110, 689370 7724110))

Comment: Please edit your question to include responses to comments, so that those seeking to help don't have to dig through the comments for clarification.

Comment: Sorry, wrong information in my latest comment. This SQL shows the correct syntax `select ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((689370 7724110, 689370 7724130, 689350 7724130, 689330 7724130, 689330 7724170, 689350 7724170, 689350 7724230, 689370 7724230, 689370 7724210, 689410 7724210, 689430 7724210, 689430 7724130, 689410 7724130, 689410 7724110, 689370 7724110))',25833);`

Comment: I can not do a select if I have not manage to post any data? or what is the purpose of the select syntax?

Comment: Is there a commandline to verify that I have installed my postgis correctly? on windows..

Comment: If you look at my example, it makes a select from inline and you do not need any table for running it from a SQL window. You can use the PSQL command line window for executing the SQL query. Or install PGAdmin and use the Query tool that comes with the installation.

Comment: Ah, that makes sence! If I do this in the psql window I still get  the same error: LINE 1: select ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((689370 7724110, 689370 772...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
test_detaval=#

Comment: If I open psql and do: \df <schema>.* I get 0 rows. same with \df ST_.*

Answer (score 3):

You are using the PostgreSQL geometry type:

`polygon`

If you want to use PostGIS you need the PostGIS geometry type in the first query:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test_insert_shape (uuid varchar PRIMARY KEY, wkt geometry (Polygon) );')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply: I get this:psycopg2.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist

Comment: Sounds like a user roles issue. Try running in PGAdmin first.

Comment: Try the suggestions in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850500/postgis-installation-type-geometry-does-not-exist

Comment: I have seen that post and it asks to Create extension postgis, which I have allready done. see original post.

Comment: Could there bee something wrong with the installation? running on windows..

Answer (score -2):

it was indeed this line that was faulty:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test_insert_shape (uuid varchar PRIMARY KEY, wkt polygon);')
```

I change it and the following lines to:

```
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test_insert_shape (uuid varchar PRIMARY KEY, wkb_geometry geometry);')

cur.execute('CREATE INDEX test_insert_shape_polygon_idx ON test_insert_shape USING GIST (wkb_geometry);')

cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO test_insert_shape (uuid, wkb_geometry) VALUES (\'iaufiubasdfasdfgsd\', ST_GeomFromText( \'POLYGON ((689370 7724110, 689370 7724130, 689350 7724130, 689330 7724130, 689330 7724170, 689350 7724170, 689350 7724230, 689370 7724230, 689370 7724210, 689410 7724210, 689430 7724210, 689430 7724130, 689410 7724130, 689410 7724110, 689370 7724110))\', 25833);')
```

someone did point this out in the comment, but I don't know why I failed to get it right the first time.

Comment: I forgot to tell. In the meanwhile I also did a re-installation where I choose not to create spatial databse upon installation. (my first installation took a long time to execute this process, where I had to kill the last process) In case there was something else causing the error.